# Find points at which tangent line to given curve is perpendicular to line l.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The data is here:

$x = t \ln t \\
y = 2 t^2 \ln t + t^2 \\
l: x+4y-2=0  \implies y=-\frac  1 4 x + \frac 1 2$

I know that I need to find the slope and in this case it's $4$. I also know that in order to count $t$ I need to count $\frac {{\rm d} y} {{\rm d} x}$. The question is what happens after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:we have $\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{4t(\ln(t)+1)}{\ln(t)+1}$